# исключить дублирование кода в верстке, ангуляр

Tags: angular

В верстке имеется 2 абсолютно идентичных шаблона для отображения массива, разница лишь в названии (они же есть в скрипте). 
Планируется сделать еще несколько аналогичных шаблонов для хранения данных новых массивов.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы шаблон был в единственном числе в верстке, а название массива бы динамически менялось в зависимости от условия отображения массива (с помощью switch / case разве что...может у вас есть еще какие идеи дабы реализовать подобное)

Отображение того или иного массива будет при клике на кнопку с названием массива. 
Если отображается один массив, второй и остальные скрываются

```js
  get allMovies(): Array<IMovie> {
    return this.movies.filter((m) => {
      const search = this.search.toLowerCase();
      const film = m.film.toLowerCase();
      return !m.seen && m.year <= +this.rangeYear && film.includes(search);
    });
  }

  get seenMovies(): Array<IMovie> {
    return this.movies.filter((n) => {
      const search = this.search.toLowerCase();
      const film = n.film.toLowerCase();
      return n.seen && n.year <= +this.rangeYear && film.includes(search);
    });
  }
```

```html
 <div class="movieApp">
 
    <h1 >Все фильмы</h1>
    <div class="movieApp__movieList">
      <div *ngFor="let film of allMovies">
        <app-movie-card [movie]="film" (onOpenModal)="showMoreInformation($event)"></app-movie-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Просмотренные</h1>
    <div class="movieApp__movieList">
      <div *ngFor="let film of seenMovies">
        <app-movie-card [movie]="film" (onOpenModal)="showMoreInformation($event)"></app-movie-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: вынеси h1 и div.movieApp__movieList в отдельный компонент. в качестве входных параметров будешь передавать текст заголовка и массив для перебора. будет у тебя один блок занимать 1 строчку кода и выглядеть как-то так <app-mycomponent [title]="titleVariable" [arr]="myArr"></app-mycomponent> а потом можно будет даже в ts организовать массив объектов вида {title, arr} и вывести app-mycomponent через ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем же `switch-case` если верстка у вас повторяется?

Я бы сделал проще:

```
<div class="movieApp">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="movies; context: { $implicit: allMovies, title: 'Все фильмы' }"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="movies; context: { $implicit: seenMovies, title: 'Просмотренные' }"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #movies let-movies let-title="title">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <div class="movieApp__movieList">
    <div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
        <app-movie-card
          [movie]="movie"
          (onOpenModal)="showMoreInformation($event)"
        ></app-movie-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Весь повторяющийся шаблон мы вынесли в `ng-template`. Директива `ngTemplateOutlet` входным параметром принимает ссылку на якорь (`ng-template`). `ngTemplateOutletContext` - это контекст, который доступен внутри `ng-template` и к свойствам которого можно получить доступ через контекстные переменные (`let-*`).

[Ссылка на API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

Comment: я новичок даже в верстке в принципе. за 2 месяца обучения изучила все равно процентов 20 от того, что знают опытные разработчики) 
на ошибках учатся. Показалось, что свич кейс - это то, что мне нужно... 
Спасибо!

Comment: @nbelle все же мой совет вам пока что уделить больше времени изучению JS, нежели Angular, это будет продуктивнее :)